# Forward typo emails

Tags: email, forwarding, web-hosting

I am not sure how to ask or if this is the correct place to ask.

Many years ago I got a domain name and email from godaddy.com.  The plan included 5 email addresses, and included a feature where any emails sent to an account that was not one of the five would be forwarded to the primary account.  I am no longer seeing that service offered, and want to know what it is called so I can shop for it.  I saw some place with a package offering forwarding for 400 something, it did not seem like the same thing.

Example:

- Primary@example.com is one of the 5 accounts, it gets and sends emails
- Secondary@example.com is one of the 5 accounts, it gets and sends emails
- Typo@example.com is **not** one of the 5 accounts, any mail sent to it goes to Primary@example.com where it can be read, any responses to the email would need to come from Primary@example.com

What is this service called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to know what it's called, so that you can search for providers which offer it, the usual term I've seen is **a "catch all" e-mail account**.

Actually, the relationship between e-mail addresses and mailboxes can be quite complex, with multiple addresses directing their mail to one mailbox, or one address directing its mail to multiple mailboxes. Most providers hide this, and give a sensible default of one e-mail address = one mailbox with a matching name, but some do allow you to configure all sorts of stuff, including a "catch all" rule which directs mail not matching any defined address into the mailbox of your choice.